# What's the difference between algebraic data types and base types?

Tags: haskell, computer-science

I understand what G.A.D.T's are, but what is the difference between G.A.D.T's and base types (in Haskell, or elsewhere)?

Comment: You can view base types as algebraic types with a lot of constructors, so eg 32 bit integers have 2^32 constructors.

Comment: What do you mean by "base type"?

Comment: Is this question about ADTs or GADTs? They are not the same.

Comment: @liminalisht I mentioned G.A.D.T's, I know they're not the same.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you mean regular `data` declarations vs. types like `Int` or generalized algebraic data types using the GADTs extension, so if this doesn't answer your question then please clarify.

Normal `data` declarations let you create types that are a combination of products (this and that) and sums (this or that).

Some examples are:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue                      -- a sum type
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int }  -- a product type
data Address = Mail Street City Country | Email String -- both!
```

GADTs allow you to be more specific about the type of each constructor.  Here's my favorite example:

```
-- helper types to encode natural numbers
data Z     -- zero
data S n   -- successor

-- a list that encodes its size in its type
data List a n where
  Nil :: List a Z
  Cons :: a -> List a n -> List a (S n)

-- head that cannot be called on an empty list!
head :: List a (S n) -> a
head (Cons h _) = h

-- tail that cannot be called on a empty list!
tail :: List a (S n) -> List a n
tail (Cons _ t) = t
```

Note that we cannot do this trick with normal data declarations like

```
data List a n = Nil | Cons a (List a n)
```

because there's no way to specify that `Nil`'s type is `List a Z` and that `Cons` increments the size of the list by one.